# Convert subquery in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I have subquery in SQL like this

```
SELECT A.DOCID 
FROM mstdocs a, mstdocstats b 
WHERE a.DOCID = b.DOCID 
AND b.VID = '1' 
AND A.DOCID NOT IN (SELECT a.docid 
                    FROM mstdocs a, mstdocstats b 
                    WHERE a.DOCID = b.DOCID 
                    AND b.VID = '1' 
                    AND a.VTAID = '2') 
GROUP BY A.DOCID
```

How to convert that query in LINQ.
thanks for any answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can separate this question into two parts.
First, you can select a not in list

```
var notInList = from a in db.mstdocs
                        join b in db.mstdocstats on a.DOCID equals b.DOCID
                        where a.VID == "1" && b.VTAID == "2"
                        select a.DOCID;
```

Then you can use this list to get what you want:

```
var result = from a in db.mstdocs
                     join b in db.mstdocstats on a.DOCID equals b.DOCID
                     where !notInList.Contains(a.DOCID) && b.VID == "1"
                     group a by a.DOCID into g
                     select g.Key;
```

Comment: I'm very glad that this answer helps you : )

Comment: Hello, i want ask about last query, how if i want to select more than 1 field.. so for result i adding select new{ ...} ?